# Elementor Hello Theme - Logo showing once on website but twice if I text the link

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I'm using the Wordpress "Hello Elementor" theme, and it looks ok on my site. But when I text a link of my URL, iPhone shows a link with an image of two logos, and I can tell one has slightly different resolution than the other, so I must somehow have two logos in there.

My website is https://cutiesenterprises.com/

I have it uploaded in Wordpress and in Elementor and if I remove either one, it completely gets removed from the site. What I mean is in Wordpress it's uploaded under Dashboard/Appearance/Customize/Site Identity, and it's also uploaded at Edit With Elementor/Site Identity and then I click on Site Identity again. If I remove either of these it disappears from the site.

Like I mentioned above, it looks fine on the site, but if I try to text the link  get this

[image: Logo showing twice]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it in an indirect way. I had two versions of the logo uploaded in the image library, so I deleted one of them, and then it fixed it. I'm still not sure where that one was located because in both Wordpress and Elementor I had uploaded the same one.